# Cant create ipa for any cocos2d application, even the helloworld default app

Tags: xcode, linker, compiler-errors, cocos2d-iphone, ipa

I am trying to create ipa for any cocos2d application (even the hello world one) but i am getting this.

ld: library not found for -lz
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)![enter image description here][1]

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to post images yet. Please post a link to your screenshot instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add libz.dylib to "Link Binary with Libraries" Build Phase of your app's target. If that doesn't fux it try reinstalling Xcode because -lz should do this automatically.